# Translate css animation to wpf animation

Tags: xaml, storyboard

I am having this css rule

```
/* Effect 1: Fade in and scale up */
.md-effect-1 .md-content 
{
   transform: scale(0.7);
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Taken from the demo [Nifty Modal Window Effects](http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/)

I would like to have the same effect when I show a modal dialog in my wf app. The dialog is not a window but a UIElement with a high z-order.

It should start with opacity set to zero and scaled down to 70% since I don't know the size of the dialog.

this is the code that sets the start state for the grid, and the storyboard for the animation.

```
Grid x:Name="MyGrid" Opacity="0">
  <Grid.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.7" ScaleY="0.7"/>
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
   </Grid.RenderTransform>
  <Grid.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
       <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ModalDialogStoryboard}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

The code for the storyboard

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ModalDialogStoryboard" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
    <DoubleAnimation 
        From="0" 
        To="1" 
        Duration="0:0:02" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="MyGrid" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
         />
    <SizeAnimation To=""></SizeAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

The Opacity works but I can't find a way to scale the grid back to 100%.

Why is css so powerfull compared to xaml? I wish the good fairy would sprinkle some magic dust on XAML

OK this is working and looks exactly like the css rule. The content of the dialog is removed to keep it short.
Now I just need to find a way to put it in a style so I can apply it to any UI Element.

```
UserControl x:Class="AnimationTest.Dialog"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
         Opacity="0"
         x:Name="ModalDialogControl"
         Width="600" Height="400">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ModalDialogStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation
                From="0"
                To="1"
                Duration="0:0:0.3"
                Storyboard.TargetName="ModalDialogControl"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
        <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="ModalDialogControlScaleTransform"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
        <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="ModalDialogControlScaleTransform"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                To="1"  Duration="0:0:0.3" />
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.7" ScaleY="0.7" x:Name="ModalDialogControlScaleTransform" />
</UserControl.RenderTransform>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ModalDialogStoryboard}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

With a little help from my friends

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FadeInAndScaleUpStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.7" ScaleY="0.7" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers >
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't that complicated at all:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ModalDialogStoryboard" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
    <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
    <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"/>
    <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Note that you usually don't have to specify any `From` values. Moreover, you don't need to explicitly specify the `Storyboard.Target` or `Storyboard.TargetName` when you call `BeginStoryboard` on a specific element, as you do in the EventTrigger.

Comment: THANKS this is close to the css. is there a way to group the animations and set the duration on the group instead of repeating it for each item?

Answer (score 0):

Which animation What you want in this site (http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/) Sorry I dont know very well English.I couldn't understand exactly what you say

I did this animation for you.I hope benefits to your business.

Here is code:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ScaleAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="13.6">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="13.6">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.8" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.5" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ScaleAnimation}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Here is Grid object;

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="#FFFF6363" Margin="298,216.5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Opacity="0">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="CONTENT" FontSize="2" Opacity="0"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This put me on the right track Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"